# Processing the data from salesforce to GCP BigQuery by using python script it's throwing the Time out error

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

When cloud-function-1 is triggered, SalesForce data will be stored in GCP_Bucket-1 and Cloud-function-2 is triggered, The data should be stored in GCP BigQuery Sql database. Here the Python script is working fine. But the problem is, It is processing only few records and throwing the time out error. Can anyone please suggest me solution for this one.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in Cloud Run documentation: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#timeout

> By default, a function times out after 1 minute, but you can extend this period up to 9 minutes.

So try to increase the timeout. In the link above you have the details how you can do it.

If 9 minutes are not enough, you can use Cloud  Run that has a timeout of 1h. But keep in mind that Cloud Run needs a little more configuration than Cloud Function.